# Перенаправить запросы в TCP через nginx

Tags: nginx

У меня есть хост nginx_host на нем расположен nginx со следующим nginx.conf

```
stream
{
 server
  {
   listen 1234;
   location / {
        proxy_pass res_host1:1111;
        }
   location / {
        proxy_pass res_host2:2222;
        }

   }
}
```

Я запускаю nginx 
nginx  -s reload 
Получаю ошибку:

```
nginx: [emerg] "location" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:6
```

Я хочу чтобы nginx перенаправлял tcp запросы с nginx_host:1234 на res_host1:1111, а если он закрыт, то на res_host2:2222;
Что я делаю не так? Как это исправить?

Comment: В stream не бывает location. Это же не http

Comment: См. модуль upstream

Comment: Вы пытаетесь в контексте stream-a использовать чисто http-шную директиву location, поэтому сервер ругается о том, что она тут недопустима. Уберите location, оставьте только proxy_pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf прописал так:

```
stream 
{
    upstream backend 
    {
      server res_host1:1111;
      server res_host2:2222;
    }

    server 
    {
        listen 9999;
        proxy_pass backend;
    }
}
events 
{
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

Надеюсь кому-то это поможет настроить nginx быстрее.