# Переадресация исходящего tcp/ip

Tags: windows, tcp-ip, route

Есть программа exe без конфигов, которая отправляет запрос на адрес addressA:80.
Необходимо средствами windows перенаправить запрос на localhost:8088.
Буду рад любым идеям.

Comment: вам готовое решение? https://www.proxifier.com/

Comment: Вообще говоря я думаю это можно сделать средствами сомой windows...

Comment: Может и можно =) но мне таковые не известны =) >> `Буду рад любым идеям.`

Comment: Я подобное через nginx делал.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/842153/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8B-%D0%B2-tcp-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-nginx

Answer (score 0):

Все можно реализовать средствами Windows:

1. Локальная подмена addressA -> localhost, например, через запись в файле
   **hosts**.
2. Затем перенаправление запросов, используя внутренний функционал порт
   форвардинга. Настраивается с помощью интерфейса командной строки
   **netsh interface portproxy**

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но тогда будут перенаправляться все addressA на localhost, что в данном случае не подходит.